# Nginx does not respond to specific client-public-ip

Tags: linux, nginx, dns

I'm configuring two Domains to host two websites: `dev.example.com` and `test.example.com`

I'm using *Nginx* as a webserver and my websites, **dev** and **test**, are configured with `server_name` directive as two separate websites sharing the same host Public_IP

- When I connect to both domains using a **VPN_Public_IP** I get response 'websites' from Nginx as Expected
- When I connect to both domains using my **personal router Public-IP** I only get a response from `https://dev.example.com`, while access_log of `https://test.example.com` shows this access_log which means the request has reached the server. But with empty error_log and no response in my Browser:

> `Personal_Router_Pub_IP - - [17/Feb/2022:07:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98 Safari/537.36"`

Is it a Domain-blacklisting issue or  Client-IP-blacklisting issue, and how to identify the problem here?

Comment: I faced the same issue but didn't the solution yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Yesh the issue was that the domain is blacklisted by Router ISP following the regulations of UAE where I reside